# how to change style of element when click on anchor

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my anchor:

```
<a href="javascript:fnSelect(\\\'id\\\');" class="selectable">[Select All Code]</a>
```

When clicking on this anchor, this css style

```
ol.linenums li {
list-style: decimal;
}
```

should be changed to this ( or overwrite):

```
ol.linenums li {
list-style: none !important;
}
```

How can i achieve this?

**Update:**

This is my html structure:

```
<a href="javascript:fnSelect(\\\'id\\\');" class="selectable">[Select All Code]</a>

<ol>
<li class="L0">one</li>
<li class="L1">one</li>
<li class="L2">one</li>
</ol>
```

so the list tags inside the **ol** should be changed from style

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: So, what is the hard part? Getting a reference to li elements? Using that reference? Changing a class name? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Javascript

```js
function updateCSS() {
  var ol = document.getElementsByClassName("olList")[0];

  for (var c = 0; c < ol.classList.length; c++) {
    if (ol.classList[c] == "one") {
      ol.className = ol.className.replace("one", "two");
    } else if (ol.classList[c] == "two") {
      ol.className = ol.className.replace("two", "one");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.one {
  font-size: 12px;
  list-style: none!important;
}
.two {
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style: decimal;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="updateCSS()" class="one">Click Me</a>

<ol class="olList two">
  <li class="L0">one</li>
  <li class="L1">one</li>
  <li class="L2">one</li>
</ol>
```

#### jQuery

```js
function updateCSS() {
  $(".olList").toggleClass("two one")
}
```

```css
.one {
  font-size: 12px;
  list-style: none!important;
}
.two {
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style: decimal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="updateCSS()" class="one">Click Me</a>

<ol class="olList two">
  <li class="L0">one</li>
  <li class="L1">one</li>
  <li class="L2">one</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: **Post above updated!** This is not what i mean: the anchor is not in a list tag itself; when click on the anchor the list tags inside the **ol** below of it should change from style

Comment: @centurion I have updated my answer. I have also given a jQuery solution if you choose to use jQuery in your application.

Comment: Awesome! That's just what i needed. thanks for this solution

Answer (score 1):

create `.list_style_none` css rule

```
.list_style_none {
   list-style: none !important;
}
```

and append it to your `li` with js, it will overwrite initial `ol.linenums li` rule